# how to get table row values with the selected checkbox to servlet from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

here is my code..

```
        <form action="order" method="post">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>rate</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Manufacture Name</th>
                <th>Select Items</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${productModel.entries}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${entry.pname }</td>
                    <td>${entry.rate }</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name = "quantity" style="width: 90px; ">
                                <c:set var="total" value="${entry.currentstock}" />
                            <c:forEach begin="0" end="${total-1}" step="1" varStatus="loop">
                                <option>${loop.count}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>${entry.manu_name }</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="order" value="Confirm Order">
        </form>
```

i want to get the selected checkbox and then get those values to the servlet. not able to find a way.please guide me

Comment: Is this a Java question or a Javascript question?  These are not the same thing.

Comment: @JoeC looks like JSP, so Java Server Pages, a Java-based technology. I don't see any Javascript here.

Comment: This is a jsp question,using only jsp is tere any way to take the table row values if not how to do it with JavaScript

Comment: can you use a pseudo selector to combine selected checkbox to the array, then send this array to servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your html:

```
<option>${loop.count}</option>
```

It should be

```
<option value="${loop.count}">${loop.count}</option>
```

The `value` attribute of the selected `option` tag will be submitted to the server (servlet).
This is the default behavior of a select-option tag combination:

```
<select name="select1">
    <option value="value1">label1</option>
    <option value="value2">label2</option>
</select>
```

EDIT:

In order to submit the other values it is not enough to display them

```
<td>${entry.pname }</td>
```

You need to add form field elements like `input`

```
<td>${entry.pname}<input type="hidden" name="name" value="${entry.pname}"/></td>
```

The `type` could be `text` if you want to make the fields editable.

```
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="${entry.pname}"/></td>
```

The same should be done with all other table rows.

Additionally instead to have one form, i suggest each row to be one form. And instead of checkbox you can have submit button.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>rate</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Manufacture Name</th>
            <th>Select Items</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${productModel.entries}">
            <tr>
              <form action="order" method="post">
                ...
                <td><input type="submit" name="order" value="Confirm Order"></td>
              </form>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

    </form>
```

The above solution is for submitting single row.

But you want the user to be able to order many products at once.
So the better way is to use just a Product ID, which you know in the time of form generation. 
The form/row contains hidden input with Product ID and a select with Quantity.
After submittion you retrieve the same product from DB and have access of the details.

Comment: but how to get the selectes table row  values to the servlet...thanking beforehand

Comment: I extended the answer.

Comment: For me, this answer doesn't work. In my servlett I always geht the first row of the whole table.